# How to handle entries of zero in an otherwise normal distribution

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, normalization

I am working with the kaggle house data set. I'm trying to use neural net for this for practice. I'm trying to normalize the data. My problem is: I have one variable BsmtFinSF1 which refers to "Type 1 finished square feet" and it has a lot of values that are 0. The value zero corresponds "no basement" which, in fact, in another factor variable it corresponds to a level. For example if "Basement Condition" variable corresponds to "No Basement", that means the BsmtFinSF1 variable will be 0. Below is a histogram of BsmtFinSF1. If I'm not mistaken by my rookieness, If there were no zeros, the distrubution would have been normal. How can I normalize this or should I even normalize this?

[image: Histogram]

Comment: I have no idea why you are interested in normalization. Anyway, what you describe is zero-inflated data. That is typically modeled with two coupled models (note that a distribution is also a model). One binomial model (basement/no basement) and one model for the "success" part of the binomial model (square feet if basement). Maybe research "zero inflation" and ways of dealing with it.

Comment: I trained a model last night while I was sleeping. When I got up the first thing I did was to compute predictions on my test data. When I got the predictions they were all exactly the same except for a few different ones. I read online that this is because I didn't normalise my data. Now I know that I forgot to normalize my target variable, but I'm not sure if that's the only problem because the model trains for hours so I thought maybe I could make sure to normalize all of the subject variables as well, that way I wouldn't have a problem. Was my thinking wrong?

Comment: Can you specify what's the shape of your data? you may not need to normalize anyway? specially in the case of (true/false) or (0/1) features like this!

Comment: and are you saying that there is a linear realation between "Garage Type" and "BsmtFinSF1 "? @HarunKüfrevi

Comment: @Marios I'm sorry I gave you the wrong variable name, lets take "Basement Condition" variable instead. If by shape you mean the rows and columns of my data set, it's currently 1460 rows and 286 columns. But this is because I created a model matrix for factor variables in order to feed it to the neural net function. So some variables are in binary form. The original training data had 81 columns. Also I'm thinking both variables are somewhat dependent since if "No Basement" is true, then "BsmtFinSF1" would be 0. I'm not sure if this classifies as linear relation?

Comment: if I am understanding the question correctly, I think there is some realationship between the variables in your dataset (not necessarily a linear one), in that case check here [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-correlation-to-understand-the-relationship-between-variables/), it's so important to know and understad what realations are there!, and if you have a different scales between your features, then you may use normalization, otherwise don't.@HarunKüfrevi